# Can Putty Connect To Remote DB and Open PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, phpmyadmin

mostly likely a dumb question as I know PhpMyAdmin is a browser-based application and typically putty connects to MySql via command line.

I typically manage my dbs direcrtly via PhpMyAdmin and am wondering if through Putty I can open PhpMyAdmin or perhaps create a tunnel that will allow me to access through a physical UI.

Might be a shot in the dark here but if someone could help spoon feed me an answer on this I would very much appreciate the guidance. Not finding many useful resources online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PuTTY you can add tunnels to an open SSH connection by clicking the icon in the upper left of the PuTTY terminal sesssion and selecting change settings.  In the Category tree select Connection->SSH->Tunnels.  Add a new Tunnel by filling in an unused local port number such as 8880 and a destination of localhost:8080 and click add.  If necessary change the destination port to the one your PhpMyAdmin listens on.

Now you should be able navigate to the PhpMyAdmin on the remote machine by navigating to your local machines port 8880 by entering localhost:8880 (or whatever local port number you used) into your browser.